# loading site global variables in one place only and use everywhere

Tags: php, codeigniter, global-variables

How can I load `application/config/site_globals.php` to get variables and use them in every controller (same locig as hooks) without initiating it in every controller? I'll need to use variables and don't fancy keeping them in a session.

This is how we normally initiate it:

```
$this->load->config('site_globals');
$my_globals = $this->config->item('site');
echo $my_globals['header_note']; //for example, there are many more
```

Code above has to be replicated in every controller which is a pain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a MY_Controller which extends CI_Controller, in the MY_Controller constructor load your globals, then make sure all your other controllers extend MY_Controller instead of CI_controller.

See documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

For the record the same thing can be done for all the core classes, ie MY_Session, MY_Model etc. Makes having repeated code a lot easier if you make use of them.

Answer (score 3):

application/config/constant.php file use for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

```
    class Custom_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

  $this->load->config('site_globals');
  $my_globals = $this->config->item('site');
  echo $my_globals['header_note'];
}
```

Then, in every controller you need to use those global variables, you use it such as:

```
    class Example extends Custom_Controller
{

  //your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replaying as it allowed me to see I had an error :)